# User with Full Control can't access or edit member of a group

Tags: 2010, user-accounts

Like the title describes I have a user who is assigned full permissions but when I click on on the user groups I get a permissions error "You do not have permission to view the membership of the group".

Comment: I am seeing two groups as Full Control. For example, Group 1 and Group 2 are both full control. The people that should be full control are in Group 1. If I remove Group two, the people in Group 1 are not able to update permissions. How can I make SharePoint know that Group 1 is the owner (and true full control) group?

Answer (score 8):

This is probably due to the group being owned by a singular person.  Check the group settings for the ownership and change it to the site/collection owner group preferrably so any owners can manage the group.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but the specific user could normally access that in the past, I'll have a look but I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Go to:

`Site Actions` -> `Site Settings` -> `People and Groups` -> `[From the list of the left, select the group which you want]` -> `Settings` -> `Group Settings` -> `Make sure that "Who can view the membership of the group?" is set to "Everyone"` -> `Make sure that "Who can edit the membership of the group?" is set to "Group Members"`

Comment: I love your answer. 1) Thank you even posting your answer and 2) Thank you for posting in an clear way. You are awesome. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help out!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a group with Full Control permission level (for example, name is Group1). Let's say Group2 is the group that needs users to be added/removed.

Step 2: Under Group Settings, add Group1 as the Group Owner of Group2 (this is possible). Now all members of Group1 will be able to add/remove users to/from Group2.

Hope this makes sense.